# Elasticsearch analyzer selection on multi-field

Tags: elasticsearch

Note: I originally posted this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/YWCd7R_FfYY) but I got no responses so I thought I would try here.

I'm trying to index a single field three different ways depending on the language of the text. I'm using a field named "analyzer" to determine the analyzer for the primary sub-field using the built-in "_analyzer" field. I set this analyzer in the document based on the language of the document. The "secondary" sub-field uses the "simple" analyzer. The third sub-field is called "bigram". I want the system to use the custom "word_bigram" analyzer if it the language of the document uses whitespace between words, otherwise I want it to use the "character_bigram" analyzer (e.g., Chinese).

I can't figure out how to specify the analyzer for this third field when the document is added. My only idea right now is to break the bigram sub-field out of the multi-field into two separate fields (see below). Only one of them would be included in the document depending on the language. Depending on the answer of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395958/the-effect-of-multi-fields-and-copy-to-on-storage-size-in-elasticsearch) I'm not crazy about this idea because this may require me to store the contents of this field 3 to 4 times.

```
"body_word_bigram": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": true,
    "analyzer": "word_bigram",
    "boost": 2.0
},
"body_char_bigram":{
    "type": "string",
    "store": true,
    "analyzer": "char_bigram",
    "boost": 2.0
}
```

I've included the relevant portions of my schema below.

Settings:

```
{
    "text_document": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "word_bigram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "truncate_5", "word_bigram"]
                },
                "char_bigram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "pattern",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "char_bigram"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "truncate_5": {
                    "type": "truncate",
                    "length": 5                 
                },
                "word_bigram": {
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "max_shingle_size": 2,
                    "output_unigrams": false
                },
                "char_bigram": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "text_document": {
        "_analyzer": {
            "path": "analyzer"
        },
        "properties": {
            "body": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true,
                "fields": {
                    "secondary": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "simple"
                    },
                    "bigram": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "?",
                        "boost": 2.0
                    }
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "true",
                "index": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```